# How to upload pictures from Photos app to dropbox

Tags: ios, ipad, photos, dropbox

I was trying to upload a few images from my iPad Photos app to dropbox. However, when I clicked on the share icon(the box with an arrow pointing upward),I don't see any Dropbox to select from. The only options I have are Message, Mail,Twitter, Facebook, Flickr, Snapchat, Pocket, LinkedIn, and Evernote.

I don't want to go to the dropbox app and upload pictures there by selecting images from the photos app(assuming that it is possible). I am running the latest version of iOS(8.1) and have dropbox app as well as in the notification widgets. Still sharing to dropbox doesn't seem possible. I've tried the same thing in my 5th gen iPod touch, with the same result.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS native photos app doesn't support dropbox sharing although you can open dropbox app in you device and add files manually. Make sure you have given dropbox permission to access photos.

Details:
**Manual Upload**

Step 1

Launch the Dropbox app on your iPad, and sign in to your Dropbox account if prompted.
Manual Upload

Step 2

Navigate to the folder on your Dropbox account to which you'd like to upload a file. If you'd like to create a new folder for your files, tap the plus sign at the top of the left column and then tap "Create Folder." Enter the name of the folder, and tap the "Create" button to create your new folder.

Step 3

Tap the plus sign at the top of the left column, and then tap the "Upload Here" button.

Step 4

Tap all of the files you'd like to upload to your Dropbox, as you can upload multiple files at once. A blue check appears in the upper right corner of the files you've selected.

Step 5

Tap the "Upload" button to upload the files to your Dropbox folder.

**Automatic Upload with Camera Upload**

Step 1

Launch Dropbox on your iPad, and log in to your Dropbox account if prompted.

Step 2

Tap the gear in the lower right corner of the left column to visit your Dropbox settings.

Step 3

Tap the "Camera Upload" tab, and then switch the button from "Off" to "On." Your photos and videos automatically upload to Dropbox from your iPad's storage.

[source](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/upload-files-ipad-dropbox-69717.html)

Comment: Links may break so please can you summarize the key points of the linked page directly in your answer (so future visitors can get enough information from reading the answer alone)?

Comment: updated the answer